# What is the name for instance variable caching?

Tags: ruby, memoization

The technique of caching instance variables has a specific "academic" name but I can't remember it.   Please help me out.

```
def current_user
  @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id])
end
```

Marshaling is called Marshalling.
Lazy loading is called lazy loading.
The described technique is called ... ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Memoization. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization

Answer (score 1):

The definition of memoization is [defined at wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) to avoid repeating "calculations"